# This method not save my data. cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How save join table in darabase?
This my code not save data in join table. CakePHP 3.0.

```
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($order->products); $i++) {
        if ($order->products[$i]->id == $product->id) {


            $order->products[$i]->_joinData->amount = ($order->products[$i]->_joinData->amount + 1);


         $this->save($order->products[$i],['associated' => ['orders']]);

           var_dump( $order->products[$i]->_joinData->amount);

       return NULL;
        }
    }
```

All variables and database records exist

Comment: Your question is? :)

Comment: `saveAll` is use for save data of related model

Comment: @urfusion The question is about CakePHP 3.x, there is no `saveAll()`, saving associations works different.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($order->products); $i++) {
        if ($order->products[$i]->id == $product->id) {
            $order->products[$i]->_joinData->amount = ($order->products[$i]->_joinData->amount + 1);
            $this->Orders->OrdersProducts->save($order->products[$i]->_joinData);
           // var_dump($order->products[$i]->_joinData->amount);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

Here's how it's done!